Firebase realtime database "like" query of nested object
I have a firebase real-time database with this structure :

With a web application I need to find al documents in files that have a label that startsWith per.
In the example in attached I suppose to receive at least a document with id -O18Yjm1awCNcF-gSvYf.
I don't have a lot of experience with noSql database and no-experience with firebase, and with the documentation that I found seems that is not possible with query but only looping the responses. Which is the best way? Maybe refactor the data-structure duplicating the informations?

Firebase Realtime Database can only query for a value at a single, known location. I cannot search across an array-like structure like that you have. The common approach is convert this to a map/set structure. See the example in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value You can then do an orderByKey() combined with startAt and endAt.
